# Teams Graph API, how to place an outgoing call on Hold

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am using the graph API to place an outgoing call from a BOT to a Teams user, with this API :

```
       ret =  await graphServiceClient.Communications.Calls
            .Request()
            .AddAsync(call);
```

This works OK, and I receive callbacks to say the call is a) establishing and then b) established.

However, if I wish to place this call on Hold from the BOT using the "Participant.StartHoldMusic" call, (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/participant-startholdmusic?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request)

this does not appear possible, because the participant id is needed and this is not being passed with either of the two callbacks mentioned :

```
Establishing
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.commsNotifications",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.commsNotification",
            "changeType": "updated",
            "resource": "/app/calls/a41f5d00-0825-4221-9fd2-2924e62e55a3",
            "resourceUrl": "/communications/calls/a41f5d00-0825-4221-9fd2-2924e62e55a3",
            "resourceData": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.call",
                "state": "establishing",
                "callChainId": "fe6f4ad4-2187-45d0-967a-af93b0d9bca6"
            }
        }
    ]
}

Established:
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.commsNotifications",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.commsNotification",
            "changeType": "updated",
            "resource": "/app/calls/a41f5d00-0825-4221-9fd2-2924e62e55a3",
            "resourceUrl": "/communications/calls/a41f5d00-0825-4221-9fd2-2924e62e55a3",
            "resourceData": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.call",
                "state": "established",
                "mediaState": {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callMediaState",
                    "audio": "active"
                },
                "callChainId": "fe6f4ad4-2187-45d0-967a-af93b0d9bca6"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Also if I look at the object returned from the API to create the call (ret) it shows :
[image: Contents returned from AddAsync]

i.e. the target participant id is null.

Furthermore if I try to poll the call object to obtain the participants using the API

```
graphServiceClient.Communications.Calls[callid].Participants
                    .Request()
                    .GetAsync();
```

The participants collection comes back as null.

How can I place a call on hold using the graph API, if I have no Participant id ?

Update:
It was suggested that I treat the "MyParticipantId" as the participantid of the external party.  After establishing a call to a user I tried to hold the call using the MyParticipantId field of the call, with

[image: call to hold]

This results in an exception, code 8522 "Participant not found"

[image: Participant Not Found]

Comment: In callbacks we cannot get participants id. But after making outgoing call we get the response object. In response object we get the participants id.
Refer below doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response-1

Comment: Thank you.  As you can see from my example responses above for an outgoing call, I am not getting this participant information.  Any idea why ?

Comment: You have shared callback responses. In callback we don't get participant information. When you placed outgoing call then response object also we get. In response object we get the participants information.
In your example what you get in ret variable?

Comment: That is a great point, thank you.  I have pasted the contents of this object after a call has been initiated.   Although the "MyParticipantId" is set, and the Targets collection has one entry, the ParticipantId is null.   Please see image added above from Visual Studio.  How can I get the Participant Id of the target of the call, so I can put them on hold ?

Comment: As per my understanding "MyParticipantId" is the Participant Id of the target of the call. Using "MyParticipantId" you can put the call on hold.

Comment: Thank you I will look at that again.

Comment: OK, I made an outgoing call and attempted to hold the call after it was answered using the MyParticipantId, and it generated the following exception when I called .StartHoldMusic :  Code: 8522 Message: Participant not found.   I will try to evidence this above in the original question.   Either this is not the ParticipantId of the target, or something else is wrong.

Comment: We are checking on it. We will let you know.

Comment: @Nivedipa any progress on this please?

Comment: Still we are checking this internally. update you soon

Comment: We have checked this. In response object in Target property =>Identity=>User=>Id we get the participants Id.
Please check following image https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTGb8.png

Comment: Thank you for you reply.  Please note though that this is the "User" id not the participant id.  I too have this field set (User id) but the field Targets[index] =>ParticipantId is null.  What value do you have set in this structure for Particpantid ?

Comment: Also note, I have just tried to use the UserId as a ParticipantId in the StartHoldMusic call, and just as when I used the "MyParticipantId" the call threw and exception with  Code: 8522 Message: Participant not found.  Which suggests this is not the participant id of the Target user.

Comment: We have tried this and got the same as Participant not found. But when I call invite participants then got the participantid and able to put call on Hold.
We are checking this with engineering team. We will update you soon.

Comment: What we would like to do is a) make an outgoing call and be able to put it on hold, and; b) Answer an incoming call and be able to put it on hold. Preferably without involving Invite operations. Thanks

Comment: Could you please check participant id in roster update?

Comment: The only events I get following an outgoing call are 1) updated : establishing, 2) updated : established, 3) updated : established.  There are zero references to participant in these callbacks.  If I use the api to readback the participants following an outgoing (or incoming) call I get an empty structure, 0 participants.   The only time I have seen participant updates is when I carry out an invite operation.  However as I mentioned, I need to be able to answer an incoming call and put it on hold, which I cant do without a participant id.  Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This startHoldMusic API only supports group call.**

For P2P call (bot calling a Teams user) its not supported.

For group call, roster update will always happen so that bot is able to get participant id for any of the participants in the call.

This hold music feature is not to put user's Teams client on hold. The target Teams user will still be "active" in the call, but start hearing music instead of others talking.

**To make P2P working in this way, bot can just call PlayPrompt API to play audio, since there is no other people in the call.**